# Bash script if else execute once cronjob every minute

Tags: bash, cron

I have a bash script in crontab that runs every minute.
In this bash script i have a sql query which goes and check for the number
If the number is greater than predefined number then I want to move files and replace files. 
This works absolutely fine, the problem is that since this script runs every minute via crontab, when the script runs next time it overwrites the file.

Is there any logic that I can put that this code is only run once but let the cron run every minute.

here is the code

```
#!/bin/bash
count=`mysql -B -u root -ppassword -e 'select count(*) from column' table | tail -n +2`
allowed="500"

if [ "$count" -ge "$allowed" ]
then
mv /netboot/var/www/html /usr/html/
mv /netboot/var/www/back /netboot/var/www/html
echo "Not Allowed - Disable Code goes here"
else
echo "all is good for now $count"
fi
exit 0
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this by creating another if statement within the parent if.

See below.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=`mysql -B -u root -ppassword -e 'select count(*) from column' table | tail -n +2`
allowed="500"

if [ "$count" -ge "$allowed" ]
then
   if
      html folder exists in /usr/
   then
      mv /netboot/var/www/html /usr/html/
      mv /netboot/var/www/back /netboot/var/www/html
   else
   echo " "
   fi
echo "Not Allowed - Disable Code goes here"
else
echo "all is good for now $count"
fi
exit 0
```